# SPARQL Query returning strange results

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, linked-data

I am working on SPARQL since nearly 2 years, but I have never seen such strange situation in the past. (Note: I am using native triplestore)

Query1:

```
prefix leaks: <http://data.ontotext.com/resource/leaks/> 
prefix leak: <http://data.ontotext.com/resource/leak/>

SELECT * WHERE   
{  
    leaks:entity-10000001 leak:jurisdiction_description ?object.    
}
```

Query2:

```
prefix leaks: <http://data.ontotext.com/resource/leaks/> 
prefix leak: <http://data.ontotext.com/resource/leak/>

SELECT * WHERE  
{  
    leaks:entity-10000001 ?p ?object.    
}
```

Here Query1 is returning some results where as Query2 is returning no results.
If I put it in other way, merging above both queries, below query (Query3) is returning few records.

Query3:

```
prefix leaks: <http://data.ontotext.com/resource/leaks/> 
prefix leak: <http://data.ontotext.com/resource/leak/>

SELECT distinct ?s WHERE  
{  
    ?s leak:jurisdiction_description ?object.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?s ?p ?o}.  
}
```

Ideally this should not be the case. Query3 should be always with no results since second condition `?s ?p ?o` is superset of first one `?s leak:jurisdiction_description ?object`

I have no clue why is this happening.

Comment: Perhaps this is a bug in your SPARQL endpoint? Have you tried an alternative SPARQL implementation?

Comment: @hendrik we are using same endpoint since 2 years and so far we never found any such things. And this is on top of MARMOTTA. Hence trusted and reliable.

Comment: When you say you are using "native" triplestore, are you referring to Sesame's native store? If so, it's possible that this is caused by an index inconcistency. It's rare, but it happens. It's fixable by taking the store offline, deleting the inconsistent index (typically determined by its size on disk being very different from the others), then restarting - it will automatically regenerate the missing index, which will put it back in sync.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Yes Jeen, It's Sesame's native store. btw to reindex it properly, I tried reingesting data again. The same problem this time, but with different entity uri. I still get results for Query3. It can be indexing issue, but not sure how to resolve it. Could you please give me more detail how Sesame's Native store does indexing?

Comment: This is not really the forum for it. Can you open a bug report at https://github.com/eclipse/rdf4j/ so we can investigate in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to know why was this happening. For some reason indexing files (pos, sop, etc) were not synchronized properly, had gone to inconsistent state. When I tried deleting primary-triples folder under MARMOTTA_HOME, And reingested data, it started working for me since it forced to reindex triplestore data. Thanks @Jeen Broekstra for the heads up :)

Answer (score 2):

You have an issue with your triplestore, I guess
Try the same queries at http://data.ontotext.com/sparql, which is the "home" of this dataset, backed by GraphDB. Query2 provides 23 results, as expected.
The fact that it returns results for Query3 is a serious indication there is something wrong with your setup